# Cómo crear una función para volver a hacer un pedido en Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Necesitaría crear una función en wordpress desde el child theme para permitir al usuario volver a hacer un pedido con todos los productos que ha pedido anteriormente sean de un pedido inmediatamente anterior o no.
Sé que puede resultar raro pero es algo que expresamente me ha pedido el cliente y nunca había trabajado con el core de woocommerce tan desde dentro.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: has intentado algo? O al menos investigado antes de dejarnos el requerimiento?

Comment: @ffflabs sí, claro. He visto el funcionamiento que tiene wordpress con los hooks y donde se consiguen las ordenes anteriores de los usuarios. El problema es a la hora de construir una nueva orden que reuna todos los productos previamente comprados por el mismo usuario.

Comment: De acuerdo, pero ¿Podrías poner el código con que estás intentando? dado que lo que quieres no recuerdo haberlo visto en ningún plugin, es difícil ayudarte partiendo de cero

Comment: @ffflabs Actualmente tengo esta función que me devuelve todos los productos (repitiéndose) que se encuentran en las órdenes anteriores del usuario. Mi idea es filtrar los productos que devuelve para no repetirlos y formar una nueva orden con todos ellos.  

[screenshot](https://prnt.sc/11idbj0)  

Mi idea es que esta función se haga cuando el usuario pulsa un botón que se encuentre en el hook "woocommerce_before_account_orders"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la función que pones en tu screenshot (que lamentablemente no puedo probar porque no está como código) parecieras tener solucionada la parte de traer el historial de pedidos del usuario.

Dado que obtuvieses las órdenes usando `get_posts` como ahora, o via

```
$customer_orders = wc_get_orders(
    apply_filters(
          'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query',
          [
                'customer' => get_current_user_id(),
                'paginate' => false,
          ]
    )
);
```

Llegas a los productos con

```
  foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
    $order      = wc_get_order( $customer_order ); 
    $productos = $order->get_items()
  }
```

Por supuesto con las validaciones que cortocircuitan el bucle cuando, por ejemplo, no se encuentra la orden o no tiene productos, o es un borrador, etc.

Teniendo los productos puedes llenar un array asociativo con los id, de modo que un producto repetido pise esa llave en el array

```
   $product_ids=[];
   foreach($productos as $producto) {
      $product_ids[$producto->get_product_id()] = $producto->get_name();
   }
```

Da igual lo que pongas a la derecha. Lo importante es que no vas simplemente añadiendo al array sino seteando el valor de las llaves explícitamente.

Al final de ese bucle podrás obtener los IDs únicos usando `array_keys($product_ids)` .

El paso siguiente sería <strike>copiar y pegar</strike> adaptar el método `populate_cart_from_order` de la clase `WC_Cart_session` o el método `add_to_cart` de la clase `WC_Cart`, que para lo que nos convoca en cada iteración ejecutan:

```
  $cart_item_data = (array) apply_filters(
     'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 
      $cart_item_data, 
      $product_id, 
      $variation_id,
      $quantity 
  );

  $cart_id = $this->generate_cart_id( 
      $product_id, 
      $variation_id, 
      $variation, 
      $cart_item_data 
  );
```

Y con eso eventualmente se llega a :

```
  do_action( 
     'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 
     $cart_id, 
     $product_id, 
     $quantity, 
     $variation_id, 
     $variation, 
     $cart_item_data 
  );
```

En los métodos mencionados hay innumerables validaciones, y casi todas ejecutadas mediante filters y actions, de manera que no tiene sentido pesquisar eso en detalle.

después de haber iterado en todos los productos, y siempre teniendo en cuenta que quieres gatillar este flujo con un botón desde la plantilla de órdenes, cabe inferir que los productos así ingresados están en algún transiente o en la sesión, por lo que redirigir al usuario a la vista del carrito debiera reflejar lo añadido.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero, disculpándome de antemano he de decir que no estoy muy hecho a PHP y menos cuando se trata de acceder a métodos y objetos internos de wordpress/woocommerce, entiendo que todo lo que detalla es más óptimo ponerlo en un plugin aparte pero no me queda muy claro cómo aplicar todo eso que comenta. Una vez más, muchas gracias por la respuesta y disculpe mi ignorancia.  Si pudiera explicarme cómo hacerlo, estaría genial. De no ser así, intentaré probar con tantas cosas como se me ocurran.

Answer (score 0):

Deberia ser posible si te conectas al filtro "woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions" para obtener todos los pedidos que el usuario haya realizado, una vez los hayas obtenido puedes usar el filtro "woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_order_again" para obtener la url para repetir el pedido y reconstruirla usando "wp_nonce_url" y "add_query_arg", aquí un ejemplo:

Agredo este código al archivo functions.php de tu tema.

```
// Obtenemos todos los pedidos realizamos por el usuario
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'repetir_orden', 10, 2 );

function repetir_orden( $actions, $order ) {

    // Ingresamos al pedido actual y verificamos el Estado del pedido, si el estado es "Completed" entonces retornamos
    // la variable "$actions"

    if ( ! $order || ! $order->has_status( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_order_again', array( 'completed' ) ) ) || ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    return $actions;
  }

  // Obtenemos el ID del pedido y creamos una url para repetirlo basado en el id usando "wp_nonce_url" y "add_query_arg"

  $actions['order-again'] = array(
    'url'  => wp_nonce_url( add_query_arg( 'order_again', $order->get_id() ) , 'woocommerce-order_again' ),
    'name' => __( 'Repetir orden', 'woocommerce' )
  );

  // Retornamos el nuevo boton con la url
  return $actions;

}
```

Esa función debería de hacer lo que quieres, pero también puedes leer este [post](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/woocommerce_order_again_button/) ya que parece que Woocommerce tiene una función para eso usando "wc_get_template" y haciendo una llamada al archivo "order-again.php"

Comment: Buenas, antes que nada, muchísimas gracias por responder.

El problema es que esa parte la tengo hecha, que solo me sirve para repetir una orden concreta. La solución que busco es crear una nueva orden con todos los productos previamente comprados por el usuario. De igual manera como digo, muchísimas gracias por el aporte